# Installing Ubuntu 20.04 on Windows 10 UEFI pc without USB or disk drive

Tags: 20.04, hard-drive, windows-10

I know I would save a lot of time and trouble if I use USB, but for this project I can't.

I saw that I can partition then download the ISO file using Universal USB 2.0.0.3, but I am unsure if this method works for UEFI PCs or if this just work for boot legacy PCs.

Will this method work with UEFI?

Comment: Why can you not do the install method that would work easily and reliably?

Comment: Wish I could, but its a project for a big company that has a lot of red tape. No USB sticks, slows us down a lot.